# Custom "About Application" window with Mac Catalyst

Tags: swift, xcode, menuitem, mac-catalyst

Change the "About Application" window for Mac  Catalyst?
How is it done?

Answer (score 3):

Something like this:

```
#if targetEnvironment(macCatalyst)
extension AppDelegate {
override func buildMenu(with builder: UIMenuBuilder) {
    guard builder.system == .main else { return }

    // override about button
    builder.replaceChildren(ofMenu: .about) { (oldChildren) -> [UIMenuElement] in
        let menuElement = oldChildren.first
        if let uiCommand = menuElement as? UICommand {
            let aboutUICommand = UICommand(title: uiCommand.title,
            action: #selector(aboutApp(_:)))
            return [aboutUICommand]
        } else {
            return oldChildren
        }
    }
}

override func canPerformAction(_ action: Selector, withSender sender: Any?) -> Bool {
        return super.canPerformAction(action, withSender: sender)
}

override func target(forAction action: Selector, withSender sender: Any?) -> Any? {
    if action == #selector(aboutApp) {
        return self
    } else {
        return nil
    }
}

@objc func aboutApp(_ selector: Any?) {
    guard let aboutTVC = AboutViewController.createInstance() else { return; }
    rootViewController?.present(aboutTVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
} 
} 
#endif
```

Comment: Thanks very much! I did manage to link the About menu item to a modal view. Is it also possible to get the About view as a separate window ("outside" the app window)? The standard about window is separate from the app menu.

Comment: Yes, but you need to enable multi window for your app and use uiscenedelegate to manage windows